Martial arts manga with a ponytailed main character in an ancient Chinese/Japanese setting
There's this story about a main character (MC) whose name I forgot, along with most of the story. It has an ancient Chinese or Japanese tone to it. I forgot what they called those times when they were wearing kimonos and such. It's not a manhwa; it's a manga. I just can't recall it with how many isekai and manhwas there are with an MC who uses martial arts and fights.
I don't know if it's important, but I think he fights a group of people, or literally the ruler of the country. What I remember is this:

The MC had a father who was good at fighting, but he's dead or something.

The MC has a brother, I think.

He lives in a village, and it looks like either ancient Japan or China.

The MC has a ponytail.

Sometimes, in some of his fights, when he loses, he still gets up to fight while unconscious.

By the way, I think they need money, but I don't really remember.

One more thing: I think in the first chapters, there's an attack on his village.


Other than that, there's something about him attacking people who did something to his father or to him. Anyway, I remember he was in court for the thing he did. Although there was no criminal act here, the MC is a good guy and fights. Literally, most of the manga is him fighting and taking a beating.

https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/Unconscious_Objector#Anime_&_Manga

Do you remember where you read it perchance?

It's in a manga website that no longer exists it closed a few years ago
